# LibeCharts WPF - binding to a Series

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am struggling in very beginning with WPF and LiveCharts.

I am trying to implement the Starting Example (https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/Wpf/Components) but couldn't understand how it works (or better to say not working for me) and there to to place the snippet into a WPF project.

With XAML it is ok, I just put the example row into the Grid of MainWindow.xaml and while debugging it shows the element

```
<lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" />
```

But then I did not get into C# part

```
SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
{
    new LineSeries
    {
        Values = new ChartValues<double> { 3, 5, 7, 4 }
    },
    new ColumnSeries                
    {
        Values = new ChartValues<decimal> { 5, 6, 2, 7 }
    }
};
```

When I add it to `public partial class MainWindow` it is interpreted wrong.

And I do not understand what happen in the first row:

```
SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
```

As I understand, we are to create an object with a constructor which add `LineSeries` and `ColumnSeries` values to an object of class `SeriesCollection`.
So it shold be like

```
SeriesCollection mySeries = new SeriesCollection()
```

This one is compiling properly, but anyway I couldn't get a binding to `mySeries` object:

`No DataContext found for binding 'mySeries'` for my "updated" program

`No DataContext found for binding 'SeriesCollection'` for initital example

Answer (score 1):

It appears the binding requires a get/set e.g.

```
public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
```

You also require the DataContext property set in your constructor:

```
DataContext = this;
```

Otherwise the binding fails silently at runtime.

It appears the getting started guide is broken at https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Components.  I had to use the Wayback Machine to find a working copy of the getting started guide: https://web.archive.org/web/20190717052904/https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Basics